# How to upgrade/downgrade an iOS auto-renewable subscription

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

Suppose that an iOS auto-renewable subscription provides access to a service that includes a storage allotment. There are several subscription tiers that vary in the amount of storage allowed. Subscribers may wish to upgrade or downgrade their subscription as their storage needs change. The StoreKit documentation shows me how to start a subscription, but I haven't found anything that addresses upgrades or downgrades. Is there a way to do this from the application?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way to stop a renewable subscription is for the user to go to the App Store app on their phone, tap on the Apple ID button at the bottom of any page, which will bring up their account management page, where they can stop the subscriptions.